# How to load video from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In case of image we use the following code for load multiple images from firebase database in recycler view

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl)
  .into(imageview)
```

but in case of video how the code will change?
please guide me and tell what will be code for it

Answer (score 3):

Picasso is an image downloading and caching library and doesn't support playing videos.
If you wanna play a video you will have to use another aproach. You can use ExoPlayer as jonyiash answered, for example.
There is a tutorial for achieving that by using the VideoView component:

https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-13-media/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I know that but I want to load entire number of videos from firebase database in recycler view and I didn't want to place multiple urls in my application for particular one video I want to make dynamic it so how can we load multiple videos by an single url in which the video url is stored in database

Answer (score 2):

Picasso is only for pictures. I think the best way to upload videos from url is [Exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/).